# C# Best practice (LINQ) for check a string in a List/Array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

Im trying to check if a string in on a list/array of string

i know the simplest way is :

```
string[] animals = {"cat", "Dog", "Lizard", "Goat", "Mouse", "Cow"};

string MyAnimal = "Dog";

bool myAnimalIsValid = false;
foreach (string animal in animals)
{
    if (animal == MyAnimal // or animal.Contain(MyAnimal))
    {
        myAnimalIsValid = true;
    }
}

if (myAnimalIsValid)
{
    //my code
}
```

I know there is other way to do that like using Select() or Where()
Do you think there is a good optimized way to do that ?

Comment: `bool myAnimalIsValid = animals.Any(a => a == MyAnimal);`

Comment: Linq is not magic. The code still has to iterate over all items until a match is found, it just hides it behind pretty extension methods. All you're missing for an optimization is a `break`.

Comment: Rather simpler: `bool myAnimalIsValid = animals.Contains(MyAnimal)`

Comment: If you have a bunch of comparisons to make, storing the array in a HashSet might be a bit quicker.

Comment: In my case i think `bool myAnimalIsValid = animals.Any(a => a.contain(MyAnimal)); ` should be the best way thanks.

Comment: as @PavelAnikhouski mention the LINQ Any is a quick and easy way. it also only returns a bool. If you want to match more than a single item then Where should be your best bet.

Comment: Do you *have* to use a list? If the list is created once and searched many times, it's likely to be a lot better to use `HashSet` as Charlieface suggests.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach, so without substring but full-string comparison:

```
bool myAnimalIsContained = animals.Contains(MyAnimal);
```

Case insensitive:

```
bool myAnimalIsContainedOgnoringCase 
    = animals.Contains(MyAnimal, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

But you want to check if any of the animal-names in the list contains your animal as substring?

Then you can use:

```
bool myAnimalIsContainedAsSubstring = animals.Any(a => a.Contains(MyAnimal));
```

Case insensitive:

```
bool myAnimalIsContainedAsSubstringIgnoringCase 
    = animals.Any(a => a.IndexOf(MyAnimal, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim for now i have only one comparison to do but maybe later i will have others.